# How do I get tracepoints in Eclipse Oxygen to show in console?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I was reading the "New and Noteworthy" page of the just released Eclipse Oxygen. One of the new features added to the debugging platform are tracepoints. This feature seems rather useful, so I decided to try it out. I selected a line of code, clicked Run->Toggle Tracepoint. I left the tracepoint as the default (printing the name of the class and method to the system out). I then ran a unit test that I'm certain executes that line of code. The message did not print out to the console. I then ran the code coverage mode and it shows that it's clearly hitting that line of code.

What can I do to get this feature to work? Is there a step I'm not following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **launch your program in debug mode**.

*Tracepoints* are [conditional breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/breakpoints/ref-condition_option.htm) with a `System.out.println(...)` condition that does not suspend the program.

See this [video (at 43:19) which shows the new Tracepoints in action](https://youtu.be/-ozOwMmn84k?t=43m19s).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Now I feel dumb for not realizing that. :)

Comment: I like that you do not just read the _New and Noteworthy_ page but also try it out. Just in case you want to watch other Eclipse Oxygen IDE improvements in action: I made a [10-minute video of 26 other improvements](https://youtu.be/Y0-cO9wZj6w).

Comment: Nice! I'll have to check out that video.